# Higher memory usage on iPhone in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

so i've been testing my app recently and when I use my iPad to test the memory in the debug window the memory is fine, but when I test it on my iPhone it shoots way up right when the app opens and makes the app laggy. Why is this? I am using Xcode 7 and Swift

Comment: It's impossible for us to figure out what is going on without more context.  Please post your code and look at memory usage using Instruments.

Comment: Yeah but I have 30 view controller classes i'm just wondering if this is a bug in Xcode or what?

Comment: Are you using all 30 at the same time?  If so, there's your problem

Comment: What do you mean by all 30 at a time?

Comment: Are you trying to initialize and present 30 view controllers at the same time?

Comment: No I'm not the memory is fine on my iPad but high when I test on iPhone it doesn't make any sense